# How to clone visual studio community

Tags: visual-studio, installation, visual-studio-2017, clone

I have the latest version of visual studio community with lots of features I selected before. now I want to clone all of the installation from my computer into my laptop. I know there has to be a way of doing that without downloading 20 gigabytes from scratch.

I think there was a way to make a installer using command prompt. but I don't remember what it was exactly. thanks for help.

Comment: We cannot copy the installed VS from your computer to the laptop, we can create and download an offline installer with the required workloads and components at the night when you do not need to use the computer, then copy the offline installer into the laptop,

Comment: makes sense. I guess I don't have the installation files so downloading them is necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create a local copy of Visual Studio setup files,

Step 1 - [Download the Visual Studio](https://aka.ms/vs/15/release/vs_community.exe) bootstrapper for Visual Studio Community   `vs_community.exe`

Step 2 - Open a command prompt as Administrator then point to the location of the downloaded file, and use one of the commands.

To create a complete local layout with all features (this will take a long time), run:

```
vs_community.exe --layout c:\vs2017layout --lang en-US
```

For .NET desktop and Office development, run:

```
vs_community.exe --layout c:\vs2017layout --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.ManagedDesktop --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.Office --includeOptional --lang en-US
```

You can change `c:\vs2017layout` to another path as you like.

`-add` define [component IDs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/workload-component-id-vs-community) to add

ASP.NET and web development ID: `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetWeb`
.NET Core cross-platform development ID: `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetCoreTools`

For more details refer to [Install Visual Studio 2017 on low bandwidth or unreliable network environments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/install-vs-inconsistent-quality-network)

Comment: thanks. but where do visual studio update files go? I updated VS many times. I guess installation files are stored in temp folder and are deleted after updates finished?

Comment: I do have the old version installation though. hopefully the update size is smaller for that :)

Comment: `--clean` option (New in 15.3) will remove old versions of components from a layout that has been updated to a newer version.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary I want to use this answer. did you succeed to transfer component without downloading from scratch?

Comment: @NastaranHakimi To be honest I don't remember if this worked, I don't remember why I accepted this answer either. sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any features to auto-magically replicate the Visual Studio installation from one computer to another. Rather there are ways to make an offline installer for system administrators:

- [Create an offline installation of Visual Studio 2017](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/create-an-offline-installation-of-visual-studio)
- [Install Visual Studio 2017 on low bandwidth or unreliable network environments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/install-vs-inconsistent-quality-network)
- [Create a network installation of Visual Studio 2017](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/create-a-network-installation-of-visual-studio)
- [Install certificates required for Visual Studio offline installation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/install-certificates-for-visual-studio-offline)

There could be other ways, maybe you could check with the system administrators on [serverfault.com](http://serverfault.com) or on [superuser.com](http://superuser.com)?

It might be natural to expect the possibility of being able to export the list of packages installed and a way to trigger a same-configuration online installation via the web-installer.